# Which of the two is correct?

Tags: word-choice

The sentence:

This pertains to the offer [of , by] Mr. Hyde yesterday to help in our investigation.

Comment: Have you been offered Mr Hyde, or has Mr Hyde made an offer?

Comment: 'Of', corresponding to 'Mr Hyde's offer', is not wrong, but is a little garden-pathy, and is fairly unusual. 'This offer of his to ...' is more common. 'By' is fine, but I like the sound of 'made by' better here.

Comment: @Greybeard   Mr. Hyde made an offer.

Comment: Thank you for your insights, @EdwinAshworth. I guess I should have been more informative and should have written, "This report pertains to.... " 
But thank you. Your insights are well noted. :-)

Comment: Neither one is "incorrect".